# Cant verify Google Tracking code on GitHub page

Tags: html, google-analytics, github-pages

I have added Google tracking code to my new GitHub page. I have used this Analytics before on another site with no problems.

In this case I see the message: Status: Tracking Not Installed. I have tried Googles suggested placements of the tracking code without success. It is a single HTML file.

Would appreciate it if someone could have a look at the HTML source.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

correct way of declaring Google analytics API is

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');

However, in your code, you are setting -

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'timebandit.github.io');

If you want to set domain, then you can use following -

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y' {'cookieDomain': 'example.com'});

check it -

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains

Comment: @Eduardo pls check google analytics details, ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'timebandit.github.io'); format is not there. Also, it resolved the problem